# Can I simply use indirect questions?

Tags: questions-v-relatives

1. Where was the historic six point programme declared?
2. Where the historic six point programme was declared?

I know the first one is 100% correct.
Is no 2 correct?
Is any special rule with no 2?

Answer (score 2):

You can frame an indirect question like this:

> Can you tell me where the historic six point programme was declared?

Answer (score 1):

<sup>declarative</sup> The movie was filmed in Paris.

<sup>direct question</sup> Where was the movie filmed?

<sup>indirect question</sup> Do you know where the movie was filmed?

Answer (score 0):

The second sentence is not a valid question and does not have the same meaning as the first.

> 1.Where was the historic six point programme declared?

Here, you are asking for the location (physical/geographical or perhaps logical) where the declaration of the programme you refer to was made.

On the contrary:

> 2.Where the historic six point programme was declared?

Is not asking anything, and sounds more like a statement with a question mark at the end. You could perhaps use such a phrase/fragment as a sentence, but only as a statement, not a question itself. so you might have two people have an exchange like:

> **Person A**: Where should I go?
>
> **Person B**: Where the historic six point programme was declared.

Although even this is a little odd to me, I'd probably say instead:

> **Person B**: The place where the historic six point programme was declared.

Comment: But I always come across this kind of sntences as questions. I clearly understood what you explained. But, my question is is there any special or advanced rule regarding how indirect questions can be used to ask direct questions.

Comment: As far as I know, no. Your `2.` sentence is not a valid question as far as I am aware, as stated in the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: As per the possible duplicate which [stangdon](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/15971/stangdon) linked above, you can add to your second sentence to make it valid: "[Do you know] where the historic six point programme was declared?" and in fact this would be preferable as opposed to "[Do you know] where was the historic six point programme declared?".

Comment: Never do I use an indirect question until it follows an affirmative, a real question and an imperative.